# Finding the nearest value in a set of a column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I need to retrieve the nearest matching value in a fixed set values for an entire column.

I can NOT use VBA, and ideally script this in M or a calculated column in powerquery so the result can be replicated in Power BI.

The set of values that have to be matched looks as follows

```
| preceding column | Sys_size | 
===============================
| ...              |     null |
| ...              |        7 |
| ...              |        9 |
| ...              |       12 |
| ...              |       15 |
| ...              |       17 |
| ...              |     null |
```

so in short, the list above is variable (more sizes could be added or changed), and contains null (empty) values.

Second there's a bunch of variable numbers as follows

```
| preceding column | User_size |
================================
| ...              |       8.5 |
| ...              |        13 |
| ...              |         6 |
| ...              |      10.5 |
| ...              |        18 |
| ...              |        14 |
```

The result I want to obtain in my script looks like this

```
| preceding column | User_size | Sys_size |
===========================================
| ...              |       8.5 |        9 |
| ...              |        13 |       12 |
| ...              |         6 |        7 |
| ...              |      10.5 |       12 |
| ...              |        18 |       17 |
| ...              |        14 |       15 |
```

simply put, it searches the nearest Sys_size matching the User_size input. Note that in case the user's value falls exactly between two Sys_size values the result is rounded up.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771106/dax-closest-value-match-with-no-relationship?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: What is the range of your Sys_Size on the Input ? Also, is it possible to have values like 8.01 or 8.1 or 8.11 ?

Comment: DAX might be easier than M. Do you have to do it in the query editor or can you do calculated column after that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in the query editor:

First, add a custom column that calculates the minimal distance between `User_size` and `Sys_size` for each row of the `Users` table:

```
= Table.AddColumn(PreviousStepNameHere, "Dist",
  (U) => List.Min(List.Transform(List.RemoveNulls(System[Sys_size]),
                                 each Number.Abs(_ - U[User_size]))))
```

Once you have that, you can pull in `Sys_size` with a custom column with this formula:

```
if List.Contains(System[Sys_size], [User_size] + [Dist])
    then [User_size] + [Dist]
else if List.Contains(System[Sys_size], [User_size] - [Dist])
    then [User_size] - [Dist]
else null
```

(You can probably drop the `else if` and just use `else [User_size] - [Dist]` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Alexis Olson mentioned in his answer, this is a bit easier to implement using DAX Queries.

Assumptions:- You have two tables, one of those tables have Sys_size and another one has the User_Size.

Let's just use to DAX to create what we need :-

Step1:- On the modelling tab:- click on "New Table"

```
Table1= SELECTCOLUMNS(TableNameofSys_Size,"Sys_Size",TableNameofSys_Size[Sys_size]) 
Table2= SELECTCOLUMNS(TableNameofUser_Size,"User_Size",TableNameofSys_Size[User_size]) 
ReqTable = CROSSJOIN(Table1,Table2)
```

Step2:- Create the calculated columns as below on ReqTable

```
Sys_sizeNew = IF(ISBLANK(ReqTable[Sys_size]),0,ReqTable[Sys_size])
Diff = ABS(ReqTable[Sys_sizeNew] - ReqTable[User_size])
```

Step3 :- Create the measure as below on ReqTable.

```
Req System Value = CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(ReqTable[Sys_sizeNew],MAX(ReqTable[Sys_sizeNew])),FILTER(ReqTable, ReqTable[Diff] = MIN(ReqTable[Diff])))
```

Step4 :- Join ReqTable with Table2 as shown in the figure [image: Relationship Diagram].

So, the final output in the table matches with the expected as it can be seen on the below image:-
[image: Final Output]

Let me know, if it helps or not !